# Clojure: create vector of maps from list

Tags: clojure

I want to create a vector of maps like this:

```
[{:patid 0} {:patid 1} {:patid 2}]
=> [{:patid 0} {:patid 1} {:patid 2}]
```

How would I create a vector of n maps? The closest I've gotten is this:

```
(defn patientid [n]
    (interleave (repeat n :patid) (range n)))

(patientid 3)
=> (:patid 0 :patid 1 :patid 2)
```

Is there a function to convert this list into maps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
(mapv (partial hash-map :patient-id) (range 3))
=> [{:patient-id 0} {:patient-id 1} {:patient-id 2}]
```

This is mapping (`mapv` to return a vector as requested) over a range of integers, and creating a map for each one. `hash-map` is a function that takes key/value pairs, and this uses `partial` to create a partial function (that's only missing the number). For example, this is slightly longer but functionally equivalent and maybe easier to understand using a map literal:

```
(mapv (fn [n] {:patient-id n}) (range 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to keep it simple:

```
(def map-list
  (for [i (range 5)]
    {:patient-id i}))
(println map-list)

=> ({:patient-id 0} {:patient-id 1} {:patient-id 2} {:patient-id 3} {:patient-id 4})
```

If you want it in a vector (my favorite) instead of a lazy list, use `vec`:

```
(def map-vec (vec map-list))
(println map-vec)

=> [{:patient-id 0} {:patient-id 1} {:patient-id 2} {:patient-id 3} {:patient-id 4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be this:-

```
(defn generate-n [n]
  (persistent! (loop [out (transient []) x 0]
                 (if (< x n)
                   (recur (conj! out {:patient-id x}) (inc x))
                   out)))
  )
```

Here are some tests results:-

```
user=> (time (mapv (fn [n] {:patient-id n}) (range 5)))
"Elapsed time: 0.476472 msecs"
[{:patient-id 0} {:patient-id 1} {:patient-id 2} {:patient-id 3} {:patient-id 4}]

user=> (time (mapv (fn [n] {:patient-id n}) (range 5)))
"Elapsed time: 0.1545 msecs"
[{:patient-id 0} {:patient-id 1} {:patient-id 2} {:patient-id 3} {:patient-id 4}]

user=> (time (mapv (fn [n] {:patient-id n}) (range 5)))
"Elapsed time: 0.143853 msecs"
[{:patient-id 0} {:patient-id 1} {:patient-id 2} {:patient-id 3} {:patient-id 4}]

user=> (time (mapv (fn [n] {:patient-id n}) (range 5)))
"Elapsed time: 0.163187 msecs"
[{:patient-id 0} {:patient-id 1} {:patient-id 2} {:patient-id 3} {:patient-id 4}]
```

With `loop recur` :-

```
user=> (time (generate-n 5))
"Elapsed time: 0.033539 msecs"
[{:patient-id 0} {:patient-id 1} {:patient-id 2} {:patient-id 3} {:patient-id 4}]

user=> (time (generate-n 5))
"Elapsed time: 0.032465 msecs"
[{:patient-id 0} {:patient-id 1} {:patient-id 2} {:patient-id 3} {:patient-id 4}]

user=> (time (generate-n 5))
"Elapsed time: 0.031155 msecs"
[{:patient-id 0} {:patient-id 1} {:patient-id 2} {:patient-id 3} {:patient-id 4}]
```

Comment: The loop/recur answer is correct but it is *less*, not more efficient than the solution with `mapv`, which uses reducible/transients internally. You’re measuring the wrong thing.

Comment: Yes. You are right. But now I have updated my answer. Using `mapv` and my code both are almost same, but in the above Taylor Wood's solution two loops are being used which is not necessary.

Comment: Do let me know if I am wrong.. I am just a beginner :-)